# Native WebRTC without audio device

Tags: c++, webrtc

I have an audio processing server, and I'd like to be able to connect to it via WebRTC.

The native library from Google seems suitable for that (from looking at the peerconnection example): https://webrtc.org/native-code/native-apis/

But the library relies too much on the audio devices: it opens them behind the scenes. I've managed to grab the incoming audio by appending my own `AudioTrackSinkInterface` to the stream, but haven't yet found how to inject the audio into the outbound stream. And these hacks don't avoid opening the devices anyway.

How to do it cleanly?

Comment: You could [download the source](https://webrtc.org/native-code/) and rewrite the audio interface to read from your custom stream instead of a device, then compile and use the lib like normal.

Comment: @Kevin, that's what I'm asking. It's probably a very common use case, but I cant find any examples.

Comment: I doubt it's very common, actually. There are hardly any decent examples of native webrtc itself, let alone rewriting some of the audio module. Something easier might be to somehow register as an audio device in the OS and just let the library pick your stream up that way.

Comment: have u slove this question .i got same trouble as you

Comment: @sleepy2con Yes, you've got to implement your own AudioDevice class, AudioDeviceModule class and about 3 or 4 of other classes. The Google webrtc native library has probably changed a bit over time. There maybe also some opensource projects that use it now.